# Addition versus Multiplication Memory Usage misallocation?

Tags: r, memory, vector, multiplication, addition

Suppose you are running Rx64 3.5.1 on an x64 based PC running Windows 10 Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134. The system has 16 GB of physical memory. The Processor is Intel Core i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3696 Mhz, 6 Cores, 12 Logical Processors.

Now let.

```
memory.limit(99999)
test1<-rep((1001:2000)/100,60)
Ta<-outer(-test1,test1,"+")
```

"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 26.8 Gb"

```
gc()
Tm<-outer(-test1,test1,"*")
length(Tm)
[1] 3.6e+09
```

Why is this happening? Note that the number 60 used in rep can be decreased to obtain success for both addition and multiplication using outer, as well as increased so that both fail equally. Why does such an uneven threshhold exist and why is addition using more memory than multiplication in this sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the source for `outer`, you can see there's a special case for multiplication (`*`)

```
robj <- if (is.character(FUN) && FUN == "*") {
    if (!missing(...)) 
        stop("using ... with FUN = \"*\" is an error")
    as.vector(X) %*% t(as.vector(Y))
}
else {
    FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
    Y <- rep(Y, rep.int(length(X), length(Y)))
    if (length(X)) 
        X <- rep(X, times = ceiling(length(Y)/length(X)))
    FUN(X, Y, ...)
}
```

So when you do multiplication, you you get to take advantage of matrix multiplication operations which are much easier to optimize on a CPU.

The other branch first needs to expand out all the values before applying the function to them. This expansion is what's allocating the memory even before the function is being called.

Comment: This is not quite the answer though it might look like it. The problem is that although it is true that the source definitely treats multiplication differently (so this is the start of the answer). It is not true that matrix multuplication would necessarily be faster. Specifically, R uses the idea of long vectors because they are more efficient than matrices. Recall a long vector is a matrix where no dimension needs to be specified, so it therefore uses less data because it requires less specification. Also, if the first part doesn't have to expand anything out how is it arriving at an answer?

Comment: When I said matrix multiplication would be optimized, I didn't mean it would be faster. I just meant it's such a common operation that the CPU can do tricks to make it work. I cannot replicate your results on my machine. Neither work for me. When you run `sessionInfo()`, what's listed under `Matrix products:`? Did you download R from CRAN or did you compile yourself? There are special CPU machine operations that can do multiplication more efficiently than more general operations. And it's not clear to me if your machine is using swap space if it runs out of RAM.

Comment: This comment of yours is the actual answer. Thank you. I had to look at the DRAM, CMOS and BIOS to see if there were specific biases to multiplication and you are right; there were. There is SSD space being used virtually (swap space) and an optimiation routine in the firmware of the RAM. The SSD makes no distinction and so this gave the asymmetry. It turns out, multiplication is studied because of the inherent challange it presents. Whereas, it is generally assumed that if you wanted more adding you would put together more (half) adders (and then the space to hold it). This is not always so.

Comment: I am also surprised you could not reproduce the issue. So there was no rep number (in the example 60) such that you get success for multiplication but failure for addition? I assumed whatever proprietary coding was used in the firware would be more less similar industry-wide save for a few small differences. If you cannot reproduce it then it really is specific to the RAM hardware I am using. I guess the DRAM manufacturer really wasn't exaggerating when they advertised unique state-of-the-art optimizing algorithms.